# Connect Consul client on VM to Consul Server in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, consul

I'm having trouble setting up this scenario. I have a server that's running 4 VMs:

- k8s master
- k8s worker 1
- k8s worker 2
- vm1

I've deployed a Consul cluster with Helm chart into k8s cluster, resulting in 1 server on each worker node, 1 client on each worker node. Here's current config (I'm trying all sorts of things so some might be commented/disabled)

```yaml
global:
  name: consul
  enabled: true
  datacenter: dc1
  gossipEncryption:
    autoGenerate: true
  tls:
    enabled: true
    enableAutoEncrypt: true
    verify: true
  acls:
    manageSystemACLs: true
# client:
#   exposeGossipPorts: true
server:
  replicas: 2
  # exposeGossipAndRPCPorts: true
  # ports:
  #   serflan:
  #     port: 9301
  extraConfig: |
    { "log_level": "debug" }
  exposeService:
    enabled: true
    type: NodePort
    nodePort:
      http: 31500 # 8500 + 23k
      https: 31501 # 8501 + 23k
      grpc: 31503 # 8503 + 23k
      serf: 32301 # 9301 + 23k
      rpc: 31300 # 8300 + 23k
  securityContext:
    runAsNonRoot: false
    runAsUser: 0
  storageClass: nfs-synology-test
connectInject:
  enabled: true
controller:
  enabled: true
syncCatalog:
  enabled: true
dns:
  enabled: true
```

This works mostly fine in the cluster itself (I can run a Job that does a `dig` to a Consul service name and I do get a response). Now I wanted to install another Consul client, this time on the `vm1` VM and join it into my Consul in K8s cluster.

As you can see in the comments, I've tried exposing gossip and RPC ports as host ports, now instead exposing the server service as NodePort service on given ports.

From the VM I can verify with `nmap` that those ports are indeed open on TCP, but for the love of all that's holy I can't figure out what to configure in the `vm1` client. Here's my current config:

```json
{
  "server": false,
  "domain": "consul",
  "datacenter": "dc1",
  "data_dir": "/etc/consul/data",
  "tls": {
    "defaults": {
      "ca_file": "/etc/consul/tls/ca/tls.crt",
      "verify_incoming": false,
      "verify_outgoing": true
    },
    "internal_rpc": {
      "verify_server_hostname": true
    }
  },
  "auto_encrypt": { "tls": true },
  "encrypt": "redacted",
  "log_level": "DEBUG",
  "enable_syslog": true,
  "leave_on_terminate": true,
  "retry_join": [
    "192.168.1.207:32301",
    "192.168.1.208:32301",
    "10.233.94.138:8300",
    "10.233.119.94:8300"
  ],
  "advertise_addr": "192.168.1.230",
  "bind_addr": "0.0.0.0",
  "ports": { "server": 31300 },
  "acl": {
    "tokens": {
      "agent": "redacted",
      "default": "redacted"
    }
  }
}
```

I've taken the value of `encrypt` from the secret in k8s, same as the `tls.crt`. I've tried to generate a token with the GUI assigned to `client-policy`, defined as:

```
node_prefix "" {
  policy = "write"
}
service_prefix "" {
  policy = "read"
}
```

But all to no avail. The client generally fails UDP connections, tries to connect to internal k8s cluster IPs (even without me adding them to `retry_join`, again just trying), overall geting timeouts and `rpc error: lead thread didn't get connection`.

I'm out of ideas and I'm at the stage of just trying random ports and configs until I hit jackpots. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I somewhat figured out my answer so posting if anyone is stuck on the same thing. While I like exposing a service on node ports, it didn't quite work out. The servers were accessible from the `32301` port (so VM client was able to *join*), but the server themselves were advertising themselves on the pod IP which was inaccessible from outside.

The solution in my case was:

- actually use the commented out `client.exposeGossipPorts: true`, `server.exposeGossipAndRPCPorts: true` and `server.ports.serflan.port: 9301`
- `retry_join` in the config should use the node IP + `9301` port
- the way I set up the TLS cert, tokens and `encrypt` was probably right
- as far as RPC and failing UDP, the problem was in the fact that Kube cluster failed to deploy the servers and clients correctly (Serflan-UDP ports weren't exposed via UDP). When I `kubectl patch`ed it, it started to work (eventually we fixed the cluster itself instead)

Comment: I've reached the same conclusion - but this is not working out for me. As if the 9301 port means nothing to consul, or k8s. setting ip:9301 (or hostname:9301) ends up in the vm's agent timing out.